# nignx block direct access to url and allow access only from specific subdomain

Tags: nginx

I have the following situtation:

1. Service running with secure access (user/pass) through a web application at:

https://myapp.com

Inside this application (embed/iframe/etc) I configure some services that embeds data from a sub domain.

2. Subdomain services that should be embed:

https://data.myapp.com

These App embed many services in "data.myapp.com" such as "data.myapp.com/sevice1", "data.myapp.com/sevice2", etc...

But the issue is that:

I DO NOT WANT direct access for the "data.myapp.com" subdomain... I want to allow all traffic only if source is from the url https://myapp.com.

Here is how it looks like my nginx conf file:

```
server {

    server_name myapp.com;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    root /var/www/html;
}

server {
    server_name data.myapp.com;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    allow myapp.com;
    deny all;

    location /service1/ {...}
    location /service2/ {...}
    location /service3/ {...}
}
```

But it seems that I can only use `allow` with IP address and in that case the server has the same IP address.

Is there a way to block direct access to the current server_name and allow it only from another domain?

Thanks for any help!

---

#### UPDATE

I have accomplished in part to block direct access to my data.myapp.com url using referer header... but this is NOT SAFE at all, once we can manipulate the referer header...

Follow the code:

```
server {

    [...]

    if ( $http_referer !~* 'myapp.com' ) {
        return 404;
    }

    [...]
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is for?

Comment: Yes I can set Allow Origin, but I need to block direct access to it... the integration of the services is working just fine. I would like to block the direct access to the "services url" not blocking the embeding from my main application. Thanks for you comments @MichaelHampton

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have update the title to be more specific.

Comment: How can you know if it is a "direct access"? What does that even mean?

Comment: I mean... I want to block access to the url: data.myapp.com from the browser... and allow the myapp.com to embed data from data.myapp.com using iframe....

Comment: Using referer is not really recommend I know..... but do you (@MichaelHampton) has any suggestion on that check (if...) a little more secure?

Comment: Anybody can fake the referer. So there's not much point to trying to block based on it.

Comment: That's what I meant.... =)

Comment: OK, what you need to do is to think about _why_ you think you want to block this access. What do you think it would provide for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83181/discussion-between-evis-and-michael-hampton).